# Turn off default-features in dependency of dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a chain of dependencies that end in depending *optionally* on a deprecated library. Concretely, I want to use nalgebra which depends indirectly on rustc-serialize as follows:

nalgebra -> alga -> num-complex -> (optional default) rustc-serialize

I can list the num-complex dependency in my Cargo.toml file and turn off the optional rustc-serialize dependency (`num-complex = { version = "0.1.42", default-features = false }`), but is there a way to turn off this option all the way up the chain in Cargo.toml?

I have tried an alternative of cloning each of these and manipulating the local copies’ Cargo.toml file to refer to all the local dependencies, which works, but I would like a more maintainable way to do this if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [H2O states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686214/155423), this is not possible, but check their answer for a good temporary workaround to get things working again. I want to discuss why it **should not** be possible and what the long-term fix is.

In general, you cannot tell what a crate uses a dependency for. It's completely possible that *alga* makes use of the rustc-serialize functionality of *num-complex* internally.

The correct thing to do is to track the dependency chain upwards. Go to each project and add a feature that opts-in to the rustc-serialize functionality of its direct dependents. You would also add the `rustc-serialize` feature to the default features to maintain backwards compatibility.

Either you will end up being able to submit a PR to the project to improve *everyone's* case, or you will understand why what you think is optional actually isn't.

Comment: "add a feature that opts-in to the rustc-serialize" do you mean opts out of rustc-serialize?

Comment: @beardc no, features are intended to be *additive*. A crate should have features that enable additional functionality, but they can also have a default feature set. You'd make *rustc-serialize* an optional dependency and then add it to the default features to maintain backwards compatibility. A future breaking change release of the library could remove it from the default features. Then you'd go up to the next level, disable default features, add the ones the library needs, and repeat.

Answer (score 6):

I am fairly certain that this is not currently possible. I looked into doing this with Cargo's `[patch]` [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-patch-section) but it looks like you can't actually specify features in the patch section but can only overwrite the path or git url of a given dependency.

Using this section you could, however, make your workaround a bit neater. Just fork num-complex and remove the `rustc-serialize` feature from the defaults. Using cargo-patch supply your fork like this:

```
[patch.crates-io]
num-complex = { git = "https://github.com/your-github-name/num-complex.git" }
```

That way your fork will be used all the way down in the dependency chain without having to change each crate individually.

As I alluded to earlier, specifying `default-features = false` in this section doesn't seem to do anything. From looking at Cargo's code I don't think this is a bug, just a lack of a feature or a design decision. (After all, messing with dependencies like this is not really a great idea in the general case).