# Re-export optional cargo feature that can be turned off

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

With the following directory structure:

```
tree hello_dep
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── dep_a
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── dep_b
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

And the following dependency chain: `hello_dep -> dep_a -> dep_b -> (optional feature) rustc-serialize`, 
I would like to create a feature in dep_a that re-exports the optional rustc-serialize feature in dep_b.

At the bottom, I have dep_b, which has rustc-serialize as an optional default feature:

```
# dep_b/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "dep_b"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
rustc-serialize = { version = "0.3.19", optional = true }

[features]
default = ["rustc-serialize"]
```

I would like to create a feature in dep_a to optionally reexport "rustc-serialize". Here is the attempt:

```
# dep_a/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "dep_a"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
dep_b = { version = "0.1.0", path = "../dep_b" }

[features]
rustc-serialize = ["dep_b/rustc-serialize"]
default = ["rustc-serialize"]
```

However, when I try to add this as a dependency with the default off using the following Cargo.toml:

```
# hello_dep/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "hello_dep"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
dep_a = { version = "0.1.0", path = "dep_a", default-features = false, optional = true }
```

`cargo build` still yields rustc-serialize in Cargo.lock. But directly depending on dep_b correctly avoids pulling in rustc-serialize with the following line

`dep_b = { version = "0.1.0", path = "dep_b", default-features = false }`

Is this a bug in Cargo, or am I doing something wrong? Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677352/turn-off-default-features-in-dependency-of-dependency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `dep_a/Cargo.toml`, you did not specify `default-features = false` on the `dep_b` dependency. Therefore, the `rustc-serialize` feature in `dep_b` is enabled by default. The fact that you included a feature in `dep_a` to enable `dep_b`'s `rustc-serialize` doesn't change the fact that it's still enabled when `dep_a`'s feature is not enabled.

Thus, in `dep_a/Cargo.toml`, you should have:

```
[dependencies]
dep_b = { version = "0.1.0", path = "../dep_b", default-features = false }
```